# How could I make this repeat itself if the user enters 'y'?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So far this is my code. I'm learning about loops in Python, and am wondering how I could make this code repeat if the user entered 'y'.

```
while True:
    num1 = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    num2 = int(input('Please enter another number: '))

    print('The two added together are: ', num1 + num2)
    response = print('Would you like to see this again? (Enter "y" for yes): ')
```

Comment: That code *will* repeat, irrespective of the user's input. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I was trying to make it so you add two numbers together, and if you want to add two new numbers together, you can enter y. Not so it repeats on default.

Comment: So why don't you try checking what the user has input, and stopping the loop if it *isn't* `'y'`? Perhaps have a look at [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
response = 'y'
while response == 'y':
    num1 = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Please enter another number: "))

    print("The two added together are: ", num1 + num2)
    response = input("Would you like to see this again? (Enter 'y' for yes): ")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Two common ones are to either initialize `response = 'y'` and make your `while` loop `while response == 'y': ...` or do `while True: ...` and break out of the `while` loop if you don't receive a `y` from the user.  Which way you do it is a matter of preference.  I prefer the latter, because I don't like to initialize variables if I don't have to, and IMO it's more clear what's happening when someone is reading the code.

Here's an example:

```
Python 3.3.3 (v3.3.3:c3896275c0f6, Nov 18 2013, 21:19:30) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> while True:
...     num1 = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
...     num2 = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
...
...     print('The two added together are: {}'.format(num1 + num2))
...     response = input('Would you like to see this again? (Enter "y" for yes): ')
...     if response.lower() != 'y':
...         break
...
Please enter a number: 1
Please enter a number: 1
The two added together are: 2
Would you like to see this again? (Enter "y" for yes): y
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 5
The two added together are: 8
Would you like to see this again? (Enter "y" for yes): n
>>>
```

## The Next Step

As a further exercise for the student, rewrite this to accept and add an arbitrary number of integers entered one at a time, terminated by a blank line.  Bonus points for adding error checking to make certain that the user doesn't enter a string instead of a number.